# how to show a content after and a tooltip when hovering over it?

Tags: html, css

so, i need to show many lines of text (written in the html), each line withing a "p" tag.
the text in the line should be followed by the $ sign (with a bit of styling on the $) and when you hover over the $ sign (and only over the $ sign, not over the rest of the text in the line), a simple html tooltip should appear with a text determined in the html (different text for every line).

i must do it so that only the text, the tooltip title (and css the class) are determined in the p properties (html), the rest should be in the css.
the $ sign must be defined in the css, so i could change it to another sign only once in the css if i need to.

so, i tried this (styling inside html file for simplicity of presentation here):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
.my-tooltip::after {
   content: "$";
   font-size: 50%;
   vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="my-tooltip" title="text description">The Text</p>
</body>
```

but my problem is, that the tooltip is displayed even when hovering over the rest of the line, not only over the $ sign.
i understand why this is happening (because "The Text" is also affected by "my-tooltip"), but i can't think of a way to do it right.
any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
.tooltip {
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 35px 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip span:after{
    content: "$";
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: -3px 0 0 2px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip span:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span>
        <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, but this will not even show the $ sign..

Comment: know check my answer

Comment: that's works, but i need the $ sign to be defined in the css. is it even possible? gonna try Java Script as recommanded

Comment: @user6370855 check this

Comment: Awesome! works! thank you very much and thanks for the extra styling, it's nice. gonna learn your code now

Comment: @user6370855 Welcome :)

Comment: If this answer helps you then please accept my answer

Comment: Awesome! easy and detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this using `::after` instead you can do it like that.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
.my-tooltip span{
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1ex;
}
.my-tooltip{
width: fit-content;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><p class="my-tooltip">The Text<span title="text description">$</span></p></div>
</body>
```

Comment: tooltip still shown when hovering over "The Text" too

Comment: problem is, i need the $ sign in the css too, so i could easly change it to another sign

Comment: you can change it in javascript easier.

Comment: i don't know JS yet, will learn if need. but i need this to apply to many pages, will JS do this?

Comment: Sure, it's JavaScript!